# User is not authorized to delete build info even when they have the delete permission enabled in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am using Include Patterns to make sure the permissions get applied to new builds as they are created. When a promote from one repository to another or I have a specified number of builds retention and that number is reached, Artifactory will return an error of "User '****' is not authorized to delete build info. Delete permission is needed." Based on the permission assigned to the user, they have the delete permission enabled for that build.

I have a permission called build-deletion-test. When I use the following Include Patterns for the build-deletion-test permission, `TEN :: artifactory-example :: **`, a list of 6 builds appear that match the pattern. In this list of builds is a build called `TEN :: artifactory-example :: test-build4` which I would like to promote. In addition to the include pattern, the pattern includes a single user called test_delete_user. This test_delete_user has the following build actions enabled: read, annotate, deploy, and delete. When I promote a build using this user's credentials from a snapshot repo to staging repo, the promotion process completes successfully in Jenkins output but returns an error message stating the user is not authorized to delete build info. More importantly, the artifacts of the build are never moved from the original repo to the promotion repo.

When I leave everything above constant but change the Include Pattern to include all builds, the promotion goes through successfully and the error about not having delete permissions no longer appears.

**using a specific include pattern for builds message**

```
Promoting 'TEN :: artifactory-example :: test-build4' #5 to 'binaries-local-elsys-staging', using copy.
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 403,
    "message" : "User '****' is not authorized to delete build info. Delete permission is needed."
  } ]
}
Promotion completed successfully!
```

**when all builds are included message**

```
Promoting 'TEN :: artifactory-example :: test-build4' #7 to 'binaries-local-elsys-staging'.
{
  "messages" : [ {
    "level" : "INFO",
    "message" : "Skipping promotion status update: no status received."
  } ]
}
Promotion completed successfully!
```

Comment: Which Artifactory version are you using?
before 6.6 you needed admin permissions to delete the build-info file (while deploy was enough to create a build-info).
6.6 and above have introduced build permissions where-by you have the ability to add builds as resources to a permission target.

Comment: We are using version 6.9.1 and we have set the build permissions to include the delete option.